# Setup a mail server

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, mail-server

Everyone please contribute your time explaining each and every part for the configuration of the mailing server.

Answer must contain Basic steps to Advanced steps. Prerequisites with hardening security and hackers alerts tips.

And you can mention things that's necessary, might be a big help for all of us reading this post.

I need to know what are the prerequisites for setup a mail-server ?

> CONFIGURATION
>
> I have an old PC. And what to convert it into a server for personal use.
>
> It configuration is 1GB RAM and 100GB HDD.

And I was thinking to run it using Ubuntu server.

What should I do next? And is the configuration perfect?

Comment: I think you should approach your learning curve problem in a different way than re-phrasing the same question on a daily basis and posting it here again. Last time, you were given quite a few hints where to start reading, if I recall this correctly.

Comment: :) Can you can help from where to start.

Comment: Check my answer. I come up with this when searching on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ars Technica did a very nice write up on this a little while back. It goes from start to finish, outlining what each piece of software does, why you need it, and the basics on how to set it up.

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/

http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/04/taking-e-mail-back-part-4-the-finale-with-webmail-everything-after/

Note, this is a fairly complex endeavor. There are many, many ways that an incorrectly configured mail server can cause you problems, and unfortunately the benefits when everything is running perfectly are few. If you're just doing this to learn, dive right in, I did and it's certainly an experience. If, however, you plan on using this server for actually hosting the email for you or family/friends, be sure you fully understand how much work is required to set up and maintain a secure mail server, and the many ways things can go wrong.

Again, not saying what you want to do is not a worthwhile endeavor, but be sure to carefully weigh the costs and benefits.

Comment: I am just doing it to learn. And thanks for your advice @doom